# facebook PHP SDK ignore erros

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK, but I'd like to ignore the errors. They are printing out, causing user troubles. Is there any way to prevent it from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: "I just chopped off my hand. how can I ignore the blood that's spurting all over my screen". Error messages exist for a reason. Fix the errors, and the messages go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

But try removing the errors instead of ignoring them.